# Why does scrollIntoView not work in Chrome on iOS?

Tags: javascript

When a filter link `nav .fixed a` is clicked, the page is scrolled to the top of the content section `#category-content` via `scrollIntoView`.

Results in the following browsers:

**macOS**

Firefox ✅

Safari ✅

Chrome ✅

**iOS**

Firefox ✅

Safari ✅

Chrome ❌

In iOS Chrome nothing happens. The filter links work, but no page scroll. There is also no relevant CSS; `#category-content` is a direct child of `body`, with no CSS on it.

Browser versions have been updated. Caches cleared. Phone restarted. No console errors.

Is there something here that is causing it, or perhaps something about Chrome for iOS to consider?

**HTML**

```
<nav id="filters">
  <ul class=“fixed”>
    <li><a href="#" data-filter="all" class="active">All</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" data-filter="text-inputs">Text &amp; Inputs</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" data-filter="controls">Controls</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" data-filter="scrolly-stuff">Scrolly Stuff</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" data-filter="other">Other</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>


<div id="category-content">
   <!— Content —>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
document.querySelectorAll('nav .fixed a').forEach(navLink => {
  navLink.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
    // Get the element
    const categoryContent = document.getElementById('category-content');
      // Scroll to the element
      categoryContent.scrollIntoView();
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

For anyone that encounters this issue, the problem was not the JS itself that fires `scrollIntoView`. I'm lazy loading the videos and images on the page which also checks the DOM again in the event of any changes. In my case, the `data-filter`s are hiding/showing their relevant items with `opacity` and `display: none`. I had the `scrollIntoView` code lower in my JS file, below the lazy load functions which includes `update()` for that DOM check.

Unsurprisingly, placing the lazy load code lower, below `scrollIntoView` has fixed the issue. I'm not totally sure why it originally didn't work *only* in Chrome and *only* on iOS (didn't test Android however), as opposed to always, but it's working well now.